# Replace string in ios

Tags: objective-c, string, replace

In objective-c I want to replace the string `"AB\(cd"` to `"AB\\(cd"`. This is what I have tried

```
NSMutableString * str = @"AB\(cd";
NSString * replace = @"\\(";
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\("
                                       withString:replace];

NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Result is `"AB(cd"` but I want it as `"AB\\\(cd"`

Please can somebody help me on this

Comment: @Popeye, I believe you have changed the total meaning of the question with the edit.

Comment: @user1190882 In what way? You can't replace a string using `iOS` you use code (In this case Objective-c) to replace the string so I have replaced this correctly

Comment: The code to this question doesn't make sense as it is `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` returns a string and you don't pass it into `str` so `str` should remain as `"AB\(cd"` when NSLogging it.

Comment: Not to mention that the compiler won't like `\(` in the string literal.

Comment: @Popeye, in beginning, I can see it as `"AB\\(CD"`, and ending I can see it as `"AB\\\(CD"`

Comment: @user1190882 With the code that the OP has shared that is impossible because the new string is never assigned to anything so it is lost and never to be seen again after the third line so when NSLogging it should be what the original string was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the return value from `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]`:

```
NSString *replaced = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\("
                                                    withString:@"\\\\("];
```

However if you want to replace the original `str` then you need to re-assign it with a mutable copy as it's an `NSMutableString`:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\("
                                     withString:@"\\\\("] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: i want it to come as AB doublebackward slash (cd

Comment: @user3115014 Yeah that's what the code in my answer should do.

Comment: if iam putting that in stackoverflow its triming one slash

Comment: @user3115014 Ah I see; I've fixed the code in my answer.